# store results of a loop in a shell variable in sh

Tags: shell, sh

I have a couple of nested loops that generate identical data over multiple iterations.

I would like to instead save this data from one of the inner loops in a shell variable.

Is there an easy way to redirect output from a loop into a variable, without modifying the loop itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loop (`for`, `while`, or `until`) is a command just like any other. You can capture its output using command substitution.

```
$ foo=$(for x in 1 2 3; do echo "Number $x"; done)
$ echo "$foo"
Number 1
Number 2
Number 3
```

However, if you mean redirect like you would redirect to a file:

```
for x in 1 2 3; do
    echo "Number $x"
done > somefile.txt
foo=$(cat somefile.txt)
```

then things get a little trickier. You can't write directly to a variable, but arguably the simplest workaround is the above, which first writes the output to a file, then reads the file back into a variable.

Comment: Thanks!  Indeed this works.  I thought `for` was special, because I've tried using it with `time`, and it didn't work out.  BTW, is there a way to leave the lines with the existing `for` loop completely untouched, e.g., have `foo=$(` on a preceding line?

Comment: Yes, you can start the command substitution on the previous line just like that, and put the closing `)` on a line by itself afterward.